# read from ttyUSB1 device serial port

Tags: c, serial-port, tty

hello i am not able to read from endless loop using c program

below is my program pls help me advance thanks

how to make endless loop in serial USB programming 
hello i am not able to read from endless loop using c program

below is my program pls help me advance thanks

how to make endless loop in serial USB programming

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(){
    int fd;
    int n;

    fd = open_port();
    char creadbyte[10];
    char buf[10];
    while(1){
        n = read(fd,creadbyte,1);

        if(creadbyte == '\n'){
            strcat(buf,creadbyte);
            break;
        }
        sleep(2);
    }
    printf("%c",creadbyte);

    close(fd);
}   

int open_port(){  
    int fd; 
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if(fd < 0){
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB1");
    }else
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);

    printf("In Open port fd = %d\n", fd);
    return(fd);

    struct termios options;
    tcgettr(fd, &options);

    cfsetispeed(&options,B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&options,B9600);

    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); 
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* Select 8 data bits */   
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;

    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options) == -1)
        printf("Error with tcsetattr = %s\n", strerror(errno));
    else
        printf("%s\n", "tcsetattr succeed");

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);

}
```

Comment: the question is about a runtime problem, however, the posted code does not compile.  Suggest when compiling to enable all warnings, then fix those warnings.  Then post an edit to the question that contains the corrected code.

Comment: Assuming that the code compiles: (1) Both copies of `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY)` are superfluous, and accomplish nothing. (2) You have opened the serial port in nonblocking mode, but have not coded the read() to handle this mode. (3) Reading one byte at a time is inefficient.  (4) You fail to test the return code of the read() for any error or count.  (5) Using nonblocking mode and sleeping probably means that you should be using blocking mode. (6) The `printf("%c",creadbyte)` should probably be `printf("%s", buf)` (+) At least you are using/modifying the termios structure properly.